# MBP Mid 2015 Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 Login Screen show a black section at right

Tags: macos

See the picture as show below. I have tried to turn off "Show notification in Login screen" for all apps. However, this still shows. I disconnected the external monitor too.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make some change on the `Login Options` under `Users & Groups` in `System Preference`, and it fix the Right Black bar issue.

The change I did is `Display login window as Name and Password` instead of `List of Users`, as shown in the picture:

[image]

Hope this helps.